# Have these two java.io.File thread safety issues been evaded?

Tags: java, multithreading, file, filesystems, thread-safety

Assuming a `Win32FileSystem` and `beginMultiThreading` runs many times simultaneously on a shared MultiThreadingClass object, what is the most possible way that this can cause a data-race or some other threading issue? I know that this is probably not thread safe, because (1) the argument to `setPath` gets reused. I see also that (2) `path` is not a final variable in `java.io.File`. However, I can't seem to find a part where this code could error out on its own due to threading issue.

```
public class MultiThreadingClass {
    private Holder h = new Holder();
    private String path ="c:\\somepath"; 
    public void beginMultiThreading(){
        h.setPath(new File(path));
        h.begin();
    }
}

public class Holder {
    private File path;
    public void setPath(File path){
        this.path = path;
    }
    public void begin(){
        System.out.println(path.getCanonicalPath()+"some string");
    }
}
```

Comment: An immutable argument gets reused..so no that's perfectly fine except if the class documents that working with several instances in different threads isn't safe (say it uses static variables internally in a non-thread-safe manner).

Comment: @Voo thanks for pointing that the argument is immutable. I changed the `setPath` argument to `File`. will this still be thread safe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example code has no multi-threading at all. So I'll assume that either multiple threads are operating on their own `MultiThreadingClass` instance, or that they are sharing a common instance between them.

Either way, this code is thread safe. The only shared state is a private string object, which is not adjusted as part of your methods.

Comment: Thanks. They're sharing a common instance between them. I edited the `setPath` argument to `File` because it's what I'm looking at. Will this still be thread safe?

Answer (score 3):

As @Duncan says, the code is currently thread-safe. But it doesn't do any file writing at this time. As you are using File objects, I have an expectation that you will be dealing with files. Once you start to write files, there are further considerations:

- Writing to a single file from multiple threads needs to be synchronized. To my knowledge, this is not "out of the box" functionality.
- Writing to the same file from different JVMs or even from different class loaders in the same JVM is much harder. (With most web frameworks, writing to a logging file from multiple web apps is an example of writing to a single file from different class loaders). You are back to using a lock file or a platform-specific mutex of some sort.

**Caveat:** It is a while since I have had to do this, so there may be more support in the latest Java concurrency package or NIO package that someone else can expand on.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the hazards of writing to files from multiple threads.

Comment: FileChannel is a Java NIO class which has thread safety. From the FileChannel Javadoc, "File channels are safe for use by multiple concurrent threads [from within the same JVM]."